# How can i convert many variable to int in one line

Tags: python-3.x

I started to learn Python a few days ago.
I know that I can convert variables into int, such as x = int (x)
but when I have 5 variables, for example, is there a better way to convert these variables in one line? In my code, I have 2 variables, but what if I have 5 or more variables to convert, I think there is a way

You for help
(Sorry for my English)

```
x,y=input().split()
y=int(y)
x=int(x)
print(x+y)
```

Answer (score 3):

> You could use something like this .

```
a,b,c,d=[ int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one easy way of converting multiple variables into integer in python: 
`right, left, top, bottom = int(right), int(left), int(top), int(bottom)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the map function.

```
x, y = map(int, input().split())
print x + y
```

if the input was:

```
1 2
```

the output would be:

```
3
```

You could also use tuple unpacking:

```
x, y = input().split()
x, y = int(x), int(y)
```

I hope this helped you, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

This will work with any number of values:

```
# Split the input and convert each value to int
valuesAsInt = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

# Print the sum of those values
print(sum(valuesAsInt))
```

The first line is a [list comprehension](https://medium.com/better-programming/list-comprehension-in-python-8895a785550b), which is a handy way to *map* each value in a list to another value. Here you're mapping each string `x` to `int(x)`, leaving you with a list of integers.

In the second line, [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) sums the whole array, simple as that.

Comment: it should be `input().split()`. Otherwise getting `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'` error.

Answer (score 0):

Check this small example.

```py
>>> values = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
1 2 3 4 5
>>> values
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> values[0]
1
>>> values[1]
2
>>> values[2]
3
>>> values[3]
4
>>> values[4]
5
```

You have to enter value separated with spaces. Then it convert to integer and save into list. As a beginner you won't understand what the [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is. This is what documentation mention about it.

> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. Common applications are to make new lists where each element is the result of some operations applied to each member of another sequence or iterable, or to create a subsequence of those elements that satisfy a certain condition.

So the extracted version of `[int(x) for x in input().split()]` is similar to below function,

```py
>>> values = []
>>> input_values = input().split()
1 2 3 4 5
>>> for val in input_values:
...     values.append(int(val))
...
>>> values
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You don't need to create multiple variables to save your values, as this example all the values are saved in `values` list. So you can access the first element by `values[0]` (0th element is the first value). When the number of input values are large, let's say 100, you have to create 100 variables to save it. But you can access 100th value by `values[99]`.